# Checking the type for multi and single dimensional arrays Pandas Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I want to check if the `Multi` and `Single` are of type float or string. How would I be able to check the type of `multi dimensional` arrays and `single dimensional` arrays.

csv file:

```
Multi,Single    
[[20]|[yes]],[35|50]
```

Code:

```
import pandas pd

check = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
if (not isinstance(check["Multi"], (float, int))):
    print(f'Invalid value: {check["Multi"]} must be int or float')

if (not isinstance(check["Single"], (float, int))):
    print(f'Invalid value: {check["Single"]} must be int or float')
```

Error:

```
Invalid value: [[20]|[yes]] must be int or float
```

Comment: are trying to look at 20 and yes separately? [[20]|[yes]] is read in as string and that's what being tested. Same for [35|50], this is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Input data:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Multi,Single
[[20]|[yes]],[35|50]
[[20.5]|[-30.8]],[35.5|True]"""))
```

```py
>>> df
              Multi       Single
0      [[20]|[yes]]      [35|50]  # Expect: Multi->False, Single->True
1  [[20.5]|[-30.8]]  [35.5|True]  # Expect: Multi->True, Single->False
```

First, we keep all characters that are not `[`, `|`, `]` and try to convert to them `float`:

```py
out = df.apply(lambda sr: sr.str.findall(r'([^\[\|\]]+)')
                                .apply(lambda l: pd.Series(l)
                                                   .astype(float, errors="ignore")
                                                   .dtype == float))
```

```py
>>> out
   Multi  Single
0  False    True
1   True   False
```